# How do I create new SQL table of only unique ID duplicates and keep all other vars

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have duplicates on my unique key variable and I would like them to be in their own dataset, and to keep all columns even if those are not duplicates.

Proc sql;
Create table Duplicates as
select *
from dataset
....?Where ID is duplicated (e.g. there are multiple rows with the same ID, pull them and put them in this new table called Duplicates, keep all other columns even if they are not duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to find the IDs that have more than one row, and then select all the details for those rows:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE Duplicates AS
SELECT * FROM dataset 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, COUNT(1) count 
        FROM dataset
        GROUP BY id) counts 
    WHERE count > 1);
```

Comment: got an Error:proc sql;
 74         INSERT INTO Duplicates
 75         SELECT * FROM dataset
 76         WHERE id IN (
 77             SELECT id
 78             FROM (
 79                 SELECT id, COUNT(1) count
                                                      _____
                                                      22
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, AS, 
               CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: I've updated the query to match your sample, which looks like SAS.